# The application has stopped unexpectedly . Error-caused by: Java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-xml, android-logcat

main.java

```
package com.learnactivities;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Second.class));

        }
    });
}
```

}

activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Main" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Second.java

```
package com.learnactivities;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Second extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);
}
```

}

second.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Second" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="@string/nd" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.learnactivities"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.learnactivities.Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".second" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

I m getting following errors. I can see that error caused by java.lang.NullPointerException. I did my best searching here and there but could not get to the solution.Plz, anyone help me sort this problem out?

```
08-25 19:08:44.442: D/AndroidRuntime(276): Shutting down VM
08-25 19:08:44.442: W/dalvikvm(276): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
08-25 19:08:44.472: E/AndroidRuntime(276): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-25 19:08:44.472: E/AndroidRuntime(276): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.learnactivities/com.learnactivities.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-25 19:08:44.472: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
08-25 19:08:44.472: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-25 19:08:44.472: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-25 19:08:44.472: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-25 19:08:44.472: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-25 19:08:44.472: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-25 19:08:44.472: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-25 19:08:44.472: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-25 19:08:44.472: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-25 19:08:44.472: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-25 19:08:44.472: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-25 19:08:44.472: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-25 19:08:44.472: E/AndroidRuntime(276): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-25 19:08:44.472: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.learnactivities.Main.onCreate(Main.java:19)
08-25 19:08:44.472: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at `android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)`
`08-25 19:08:44.472: E/AndroidRuntime(276):     at` `android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)`
08-25 19:08:44.472: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: <activity android:name=".second" /> I do have this in manifest.xml.. where should i have this...?? any specific answer plz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`R.id.button1` is declared inside `second.xml`, but you are looking for it inside `activity.xml`. So in `Main`, when you do

```
   Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
```

`findViewById` is returning null

Comment: also the activity entry in manifest is wrong. Class name is `Second` but entry is `<activity android:name=".second" />` case sensitive i guess

Comment: blackbelt: could you please be quite specific... what should i do here?

Comment: agreed just added the info that i saw. @SHANKAR you need to have a button in first xml or make textview clickable by adding `android:clickable="true"` and change to `TextView b = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1)` have textview id as `textView1`

Comment: @SHANKAR  you should declare a button with that id inside activity.xml

Comment: @Raghunandan: Thank you very much for the suggestions! Something knew for me here as you have mentioned, if I use TextView than I should set android:clickable="true". Thank you very much!

Comment: @SHANKAR yes if you want to make textview clickable add that attribute in xml for textview

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your main class..

```
TextView b = (TextView ) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Second.class));

        }
    });
```

and also in manifest change like below line

```
<activity android:name=".Second" />
```